# Magento 2 : how to update <meta charset="utf-8">

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to update `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag which was added in header.

I research in admin but not found anything related to that does anyone have an idea how to update it.

[image]

Comment: you want to update with what?

Comment: i want to set like <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Answer (score 1):

Default Charset is set in Theme configuration,

You can find in the below file path

**vendor/magento/module-theme/etc/config.xml**

If you want to change this, override the file into your custom theme,

**app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/Theme/etc/config.xml**

You can change the setting in this file.

Flush cache and check it.

Comment: i tried same but not working

Comment: @NavinBhudiya, fluch cache and check it, you changed the value to what?

Comment: not working i had allready try same